# Tracking the position of a half played media item on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmediaitem

I would like to track the last position of a media item (song or podcast). I can access the total duration using the MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration property of the MPMediaItem. I am interested in way to store and track the last played position.

Does every player do this on their own ? Would I get it for free if I just play entities with the MediaPlayer ?

I have not hooked media player to play items yet, I would like to understand if I need to implement my own bookmarking method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[audioPlayer currentPlaybackTime]
```

Will give you the current playback time. I have a resume feature on a podcast player and I simply watch for interruptions with:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playPlaybackStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:self.audioPlayer];
```

and then inside that callback function, check the state:

```
 if(self.audioPlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted)
```

and record the playback time on interruption...

Comment: Thank you. Good references. Would I have to save the currentPlaybackTime of the track in my own storage if the track changes before finishing ? I want to be able to remember where it was left later. Not sure if the currentPlaybackTime is persisted somehow or I have to do it.

Comment: I save it using NSUserDefaults

Comment: Thanks... saves me quite some time.

Comment: By default it's not persisted (to my knowledge)

Comment: You can see the apple's own media player jump during playback, if you switch between two tracks that are playing. It first places the pointer to the beginning and then jumps to the position. So I was guessing that it was likely doing something like that, but didn't want to assume.

Comment: If that answered your question, please don't forget to accept it :)